# Representing an algorithm of different O and Omega complexities with Big Theta notation

Tags: time-complexity, big-o, complexity-theory

From what I've seen, Big Theta can only be used for an algorithm of the same O and Omega complexities. However I've been told that an algorithm can still be represented using Big Theta notation, regardless of the O and Omega complexities. I'm unsure how this can be the case as it seems to go against the definition of Big Theta. Thanks!

Comment: Your misconception is thinking that if an algorithm's running time is big-O of some function g, then g is *the* big-O complexity of the algorithm. But there are infinitely many other functions which the algorithm is also big-O of. Likewise for big-Omega.

Answer (score 1):

f is Big-Theta of g if and only if f is both Big-Oh and Big-Omega of g. If somebody told you otherwise, they were mistaken. Now, if f is Big-Omega of g and Big-Oh of h and g grows more slowly than h, then maybe there are toghter bounds that could admit a Theta bound, but you'd need to see.

Comment: Well, trivially every f is Big-Theta of f. So there is always an exact bound.

Comment: @kaya3 So, it is possible an algorithm could be in, for example, Big O(n^2), Big Omega(n), and be represented by Big Theta of a complexity that isn't n^2 and n? Thanks for your comments by the way, they have been helpful.

Comment: @CrackerBarrelKid55 Yes, in fact, f(n) = nlogn + 1 is both O(n^2) (because it grows asymptotically slower than quadratic) and Omega(n) (because it grows asymptotically faster than linear). Neither of these bounds is tight though; it is also O(nlogn) and Omega(nlogn) hence Theta(nlogn).